# Evaluate Expression with expression builder

Tags: ssis

I am new to ssis and I would like to evaluate this using expression builder to get the current date in bigin. Any idea?

```
DATEPART(second, getdate()) +
        DATEPART(minute, getdate()) * 100 +
        DATEPART(hour, getdate()) * 10000 +
        DATEPART(day, getdate()) * 1000000 +
        DATEPART(month, getdate()) * 100000000 +
        DATEPART(year, getdate()) * 10000000000
```

The error is

Expression cannot be evaluated.

```
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The expression contains unrecognized token "second". If "second" is a variable, it should be expressed as "@second". The specified token is not valid. If the token is intended to be a variable name, it should be prefixed with the @ symbol.

Attempt to parse the expression "DATEPART(second, getdate()) +
        DATEPART(minute, getdate()) * 100 +
        DATEPART(hour, getdate()) * 10000 +
        DATEPART(day, getdate()) * 1000000 +
        DATEPART(month, getdate()) * 100000000 +
        DATEPART(year, getdate()) * 10000000000" failed and returned error code 0xC00470A4. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)

------------------------------
```

Comment: @bilinkc I would like it to evaluate to a value in the expression. For instance, If I assign  "getdate()", it will get me today's date. I want to evaluate this value to bigInt at the time the value is evaluated by the package

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `DATEPART` in an SSIS expression is different then the syntax in TSQL. Because that helps makes our lives harder than necessary.

The first argument, `datepart`, has to be enclosed in double quotes. This should get you closer to what you're after.

```
DATEPART("second", getdate()) +
DATEPART("minute", getdate()) * 100 +
DATEPART("hour", getdate()) * 10000 +
DATEPART("day", getdate()) * 1000000 +
DATEPART("month", getdate()) * 100000000 +
DATEPART("year", getdate()) * 10000000000
```

The next error you'll get is:

> The literal "10000000000" is too large to fit into type DT_I4. The magnitude of the literal overflows the type.

You can fix that one by adding an `L` to the end of the last literal:

```
DATEPART("second", getdate()) +
DATEPART("minute", getdate()) * 100 +
DATEPART("hour", getdate()) * 10000 +
DATEPART("day", getdate()) * 1000000 +
DATEPART("month", getdate()) * 100000000 +
DATEPART("year", getdate()) * 10000000000L
```

And that evaluated correctly to `20200611143622`.

Comment: I had no idea I could use the `L` to specify the type of numeric data type in the SSIS Expression language. Thank you for teaching me something today

Comment: @billinkc, in fairness, I only learned it whilst trying to figure out why adding the double quotes didn’t fix the expression. But I’ll keep it in my back pocket....